# How to minimize a long iMessage reply to see the conversation again?

Tags: ios

When I write a reply in iMessage/SMS the input box I write in grows vertically the more I write.

Eventually it will get so tall that it takes up all the space between the contact bar at the top and the keyboard at the bottom and I can no longer see even a single line of the conversation I'm writing in.

If I carry on writing more words, I can end up writing so much that even with the keyboard closed, my writing takes up so much height that the conversation is not visible.

How can I get the input box to shrink so that it shows the conversation again?

The only workaround I've found is to select-all, cut, read conversation, paste, continue writing; it's a bit tedious

I use iOS17.2.1 on an iPhone 15

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151099/discussion-on-question-by-a-paul-haifon-iii-how-to-minimize-a-long-imessage-rep); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be a way to do this on an iPhone. Two alternatives

- break down your long message into smaller pieces and send them separately
- Copy the text typed so far and then delete it, scroll back and at the end paste it again.

Neither alternative is great, but they might help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to touch and swipe down in the empty area to the left of the message body. This will hide the keyboard and allow you to view the entire message you've typed.

I just verified myself by copying and pasting a really long chunk of text multiple times on my iPhone 15.

Comment: I'm not wanting to view the message I've typed though, I want to see the conversation (the speech bubbles/the other person) I'm replying to..

Comment: I stand a bit corrected. I tried a much longer copy/paste into the message body, and when the message body takes up the entire height of the iMessage window, one can't scroll up to see the conversation above as the message body stays fixed. I can only suggest you break a long message block into smaller chunks, instead of one massive block.

Comment: Looking at a selection of texts, all of the conversations have short message blocks. I'm having a conversation with somebody, not giving a speech. Looking through some texts, I also see where I've written to the person at the other end: "I'll put this all in an email."

Comment: Once you create smaller chunks, you can then scroll up to see the previous conversation bubbles, so long as you don't have any unsent text.